# 422 (Unprocessable Entity error when submitting form with ajax)

Tags: ajax, laravel, http-status-code-422

Why do I get error 422 when I send the form to Laravel with Ajax?

### my ajax code :

```
document.getElementById('addReplyComment').addEventListener('submit',()=> {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('comments.reply')}}",
            data: $('#addReplyComment').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response)

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });
    }
```

### controller code :

```
public function showCommentModal(Request $request){
    if(\request()->ajax()){
        $data = $request->validate([
            'commentable_id' => 'required',
            'commentable_type' => 'required',
            'parent_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        return view('layouts.modalReplyComment',compact('data'));
   }
    return response('just ajax request');
}
```

### form:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" id="addReplyComment">
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="commentable_id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="commentable_type" value="{{ get_class($product) }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{$comment->id}}">
  <button type="submit"data-toggle="modal"data-id="{{$parentComment->id}}"title="reply">
    <img src="{{asset('images/reply.png')}}" alt="reply" height="20px"width="20px">
  </button>
</form>
```

The request is empty when I get dd($request).

Comment: 422 means your validation is thrown. are you sure you have correct posted data?

Comment: I dont know , The request is empty when I get dd($request). Apparently everything was done right

Comment: you have to make sure you have correct posted data in the ajax's `data` property

Comment: Console log like this :  **_token=k70t9Q9KZxRyqzM70d7N0cYHXgXHvDbZXoKvoMBD&commentable_id=32&commentable_type=App%5CModels%5CProduct&parent_id=41**